# StandardAnalyzer with stemming

Tags: lucene, stemming, porter-stemmer

Is there a way to integrate `PorterStemFilter` into `StandardAnalyzer` in Lucene, or do I have to copy/paste `StandardAnalyzers` source code, and add the filter, since `StandardAnalyzer` is defined as final class. Is there any smarter way?

Also, if I would like not to consider numbers, how can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use this combination for English text analysis, then you should use Lucene's `EnglishAnalyzer`. Otherwise, you could create a new `Analyzer` that extends the `AnalyzerWraper` as shown below.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.AnalyzerWrapper;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.TypeTokenFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.PorterStemFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;


public class PorterAnalyzer extends AnalyzerWrapper {

  private Analyzer baseAnalyzer;

  public PorterAnalyzer(Analyzer baseAnalyzer) {
      this.baseAnalyzer = baseAnalyzer;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
      baseAnalyzer.close();
      super.close();
  }

  @Override
  protected Analyzer getWrappedAnalyzer(String fieldName)
  {
      return baseAnalyzer;
  }

  @Override
  protected TokenStreamComponents wrapComponents(String fieldName, TokenStreamComponents components)
  {
      TokenStream ts = components.getTokenStream();
      Set<String> filteredTypes = new HashSet<>();
      filteredTypes.add("<NUM>");
      TypeTokenFilter numberFilter = new TypeTokenFilter(Version.LUCENE_46,ts, filteredTypes);

      PorterStemFilter porterStem = new PorterStemFilter(numberFilter);
      return new TokenStreamComponents(components.getTokenizer(), porterStem);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {

      //Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46);
      PorterAnalyzer analyzer = new PorterAnalyzer(new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_46));
      String text = "This is a testing example. It should tests the Porter stemmer version 111";

      TokenStream ts = analyzer.tokenStream("fieldName", new StringReader(text));
      ts.reset();

      while (ts.incrementToken()){
          CharTermAttribute ca = ts.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

          System.out.println(ca.toString());
      }
      analyzer.close();
  }

}
```

The code above is based on this [lucene forum thread's](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Using-an-AnalyzerWrapper-with-ASCIIFoldingFilter-td4047763.html). The main work is implemented by the wrapComponents method. You first get the TokenStream object from the wrapped analyzer, you then shoud apply a type filter to ignore numerical tokens. Lastly, you apply the porter stemmer filter. I hope it is clear.