# Lucene 4 - How to discard numeric terms in index?

Tags: java, lucene, apache-tika, standardanalyzer

I'm using [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) to parse xml document before indexing with [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/).

This is Tika part:

```
  BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(10*1024*1024);
  Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
  FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(f);
  ParseContext pcontext = new ParseContext();

  //Xml parser
  XMLParser xmlparser = new XMLParser(); 
  xmlparser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata, pcontext);

  return handler.toString();// return simple text
```

I use StandardAnalyzer with stop words list to Tokenize my document :

```
 analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET);  // using stop words
```

Can I discard numeric terms because I dont need it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714455/standardanalyzer-with-stemming) answered, hopefully covers your scenario?

Comment: `TokenStream ts = components.getTokenStream();
      Set<String> filteredTypes = new HashSet<>();
      filteredTypes.add("<NUM>");
      TypeTokenFilter numberFilter = newTypeTokenFilter(Version.LUCENE_46,ts, filteredTypes);`


He use TokenFilter to ignor numerical term.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: it's not realy usefull,i dont need to use porterStem analyser but i just need to filtre a numerical term

Comment: Just ignore the stemmer part and only use code you pasted just above.

Comment: ok i will try with this , thank