# Greek words stemming Lucene

Tags: lucene, stemming

Is there any way to stem single Greek words with Lucene?  Do I need to index the String, or there a simpler way?  I did some research and I found this [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.search.snowball/1268), but I don't really know how to use the Greek Stemming Filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to do anything with `GreekStemFilter` directly.  Just use [`GreekAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/el/GreekAnalyzer.html).  It includes the stemmer.

Comment: Ok, i found the answer.It is similar to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714455/standardanalyzer-with-stemming)